# Где глобальный lua конфиг для nvim (neovim)

Tags: lua, vim, vimrc

Не могу понять где прописать конфиг чтобы он был глобальным (через sudo неприятно видеть голый nvim). У меня конфиг на lua, так что хотелось бы его перенести, а куда - непонятно.

Comment: `/etc/vimrc` или что-то около того?

Comment: Да, именно такой, только для neovim. vimrc для vim, для nvim свой конфиг. Я указал в тегах vim потому что nvim тега не было

Comment: Если полистать документацию, то можно по аналогии предположить `/etc/xdg/nvim/init.lua` но я не проверял

Comment: не работает, но я нашел ответ

Answer (score 1):

в /etc/xdg/nvim/sysinit.vim можно подключать lua файлы через lua require('')

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/852893)

Comment: @DaemonHK это исчерпывающий ответ

Comment: @andreymal да он больше как UPD к вопросу выглядит

Comment: Был вопрос как использовать глобальный конфиг на lua для nvim, я нашел ответ именно на этот вопрос. Да, он короткий, тут нечего добавить. Разве что я из истории, я нашел обсуждение реализации sysinit.lua, где сообщалось что глобальный конфиг это зло и не нужно, и поэтому реализовывать прямое подключение sysinit.lua не будут.